# Не удаётся повторно запустить приложение

Tags: instagram

Приветствую всех форумчан! У меня сложилась необычная проблема: на Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) не открывается инста после установки (живу за пределами РФ - в горной Киргизии, т.е. VPN не надо)

Скачал апк файл, установил instagram lite сначала последнюю версию (320.***.***), открылся и повис на логотипе загрузки.
Потом установил версию 268.0.0.5.116 - открылся, выполнил вход, запостил сторис. Сворачиваю приложение, через 5 мин открываю - и снова повис на лого загрузки. Снёс, установил - снова запустился, прогрузился, повторно не открывается.

Comment: `Скачал апк файл, установил instagram lite` может лучше через Google Play устанавливать?

Comment: Михаил, Ваша идея очень хороша. Проблема в том, что GP не дает установить инсту - свободных 700 МБ его вообще никак не устраивают.